# Open current file in Vim

Tags: shell-command

I've got this from EmacsWiki:

```
(defun my/open-current-file-in-vim ()
  (interactive)
  (async-shell-command
   (format "gvim +%d %s"
           (+ (if (bolp) 1 0) (count-lines 1 (point)))
           (shell-quote-argument buffer-file-name))))
```

I've tried replacing `gvim` with `vim` but it opens Vim within Emacs. Is it possible to open Vim in external terminal and not show `*Async Shell Command*` buffer at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just adjust the shell command string to actually invoke your terminal emulator. For example with xterm:

```
(defun my/open-current-file-in-vim ()
  (interactive)
  (async-shell-command
   (format "xterm -e gvim +%d %s"
           (+ (if (bolp) 1 0) (count-lines 1 (point)))
           (shell-quote-argument buffer-file-name))))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there a way not to show the async shell command buffer, I've tried giving `async-shell-command` nil nil after the shell command but that didn't work. This buffer is redundant especially if there is no output in it, it's basically empty.

Comment: Also, with the new external terminal, I have a weird problem, there is a lot of overlay on the line where the cursor is as if it has wrapped around a very long line, it becomes fine after I resize/redraw the terminal window. I am using `i3` window manager, I suppose it is an `i3` problem, only happens with the above function.

Comment: `async-shell-command` is the wrong tool for that and it shows with that buffer. Use `start-process` like so: `(start-process "vim" nil "xterm" "-e" "vim" "+10" "/etc/passwd")`.

Comment: Thank you so much!